# For loop and prompt

Tags: javascript, for-loop, command-prompt

Hello What is the problem in my code:

```js
var question = prompt("What is your favorite cars?");
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];

for (cars = 0; cars <= 3; cars+= 3) {
  if (question === cars) {
    alert("That is a great car!");
  } else {
    alert("Nah, there is better choices!");
  }
}
```

It does not activate first alert even if you insert some of the cars from array. But when i change sign from === to !== then first alert is activated.

Now i thought that it goes like this: When i ask the question and user insert answer from my array, then if the answer equal(===) with my array(cars) first alert will run if not(else) then my second alert should run. But in this case only my second alert run whatever is user's answer.
I know that there is probably posabilities to do this without "for loop" but i have to try this way.
Am I wrong with code or my logic here is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). The way you iterate over the items in the cars array is incorrect.

```js
var question = prompt("What is your favorite cars?");
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];

for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  if (question === cars[i]) {
    alert("That is a great car!");
    break;
  } else {
    alert("Nah, there is better choices!");
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for loop:

```js
var question = prompt("What is your favorite cars?");
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];


  if (cars.indexOf(question)!==-1) {
    alert("That is a great car!");
  } else {
    alert("Nah, there is better choices!");
  }
```

You can use indexOf method to search array...

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you define the `cars` variable here:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
```

but then *on the very next line* completely replace that with a `0`:

```
cars = 0
```

If you want to store multiple things, use multiple variables:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i += 3) {
    //...
```

Also, this will *never* be true:

```
if (question === cars) {
```

because `cars` is a number (`0`) in your current code or an array in my version and `question` is a string (the user's response).  If you want to compare to a value in the *array*, you probably want this:

```
if (question === cars[i]) {
```

Aside from that, it's not really clear what you're logically trying to do in that loop.  It will only iterate once, because you immediately add 3 to the incrementing value which terminates the loop (because the loop only goes up to 3).  So you don't really need a loop at all if you're just trying to compare it to the first value in the array and *only* that value.

Or, if you *are* trying to loop through the whole array, then logically you're going to get 4 messages.  One of which may be the first message, the rest will be the second message.  Which may be confusing to a user.

Answer (score 1):

You made a lot of mistakes in your code. What you probably want is this:

```
var inArray = false;
var question = prompt("What is your favorite cars?");
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];

for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) { 
  if (question === cars[i]) {
    inArray = true;
  }
}

if(inArray){
    alert('great');
}else{
    alert('nah');
}
```

1) your for-loop was constructed wrong - you should loop through the length of your array
2) if you put your alert in the forloop it will give popups equal to the amount of items in your array(due to the else condition)
3) check equality on the item in your array using cars[i], not against the total array (cars)

Comment: Thank you! If it is not too much to ask, can you, please, explain in couple of sentences, what did you do here?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var question = prompt("What is your favorite cars?");
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];

for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  if (question === cars[i]) {
    alert("That is a great car!");
  } else {
    alert("Nah, there is better choices!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look below.  You needed to access the individual elements in your cars array and make increments of 1 in your for loop.

```
var question = prompt("What is your favorite cars?");
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];

for (i= 0; i < 3; i+= 1) {
  if (cars[i] === question) {
    alert("That is a great car!");
  } else {
    alert("Nah, there is better choices!");
  }
}
```